# Selection Sort Algorithm confusion

Tags: java

I am in my first semester for computer science, and I'm learning about the selection sort algorithm in Java. I understand everything up to "minValue = array[index];" but I don't get anything after that. Can someone give an explanation? Thanks!

```
public static void selectionSort(int[]array)
{
    int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;

    for(startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length-1);StartScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for(index = startScan + 1; index <array.length; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
   
                // I don't understand what the code below this comment does for the algorithm

                minIndex = index
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening is , in the inner for loop you are finding the min value and its index  and then after inner loop is complete , it is swaping  min value with the element at startScan. So after first pass , you will have the minimum element at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation is as below :

*What is happening is , in the inner for loop you are finding the min value with respect to the current element as per outer loop and its index and then after inner loop is complete , it is swaping min value with the element at startScan. So after first pass , you will have the minimum element at index 0. Similarly , in next pass you will second minimum at index 1 and so on.*

Hope it is clear!